# Extending the period for causing a wash loss

Tags: wash-sale

I sold a stock at a loss and when I buy it back cheaper I want that purchase to cause the loss to be a wash loss. Problem is that I might not get the lowest repurchase price within 30 days.
So suppose I buy it back after 21 days. That will cause a wash loss that will add to the basis of the repurchased stock. Now if I almost immediately sell that, I will have a new loss. Does the 30 day period start anew at that point? In other words, if I buy back on day 29 thereafter, which is 50 days from the original loss, will that still cause a wash? (Paradoxically I would want it to do so)

Comment: Which country are you in?  I believe multiple countries have wash sale rules.

Comment: Why would you want that? Just curious.